# Simple way to test if string contains float eg. "8.3"

Tags: string

I thought `(defun string-integer-p (string)` was cool,
I found it in the emacswiki.

Is there a variant of it I can use to test if string contains float eg. `"8.3"`

Comment: Emacs Wiki:  `(defun string-float-p (string) (if (string-match "\\`[-+]?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]*\\'" string) t nil))` -- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook

Comment: Please provide the code for `string-integer-p` in the question, or at least link to the wiki page that defines it.

Comment: @lawlist: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @lawlist That solution neglects all the problems that result from exponent representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `string-to-number` is usable here.  It has the unfortunate property that it returns `0` for non-numeric strings (an option to return `nil` would seem sensible, especially as that's what its helper actually does); however `0` is *not* a float, so...

```
(defun my-string-float-p (str)
  "Non-nil if string STR represents a floating point number."
  (floatp (string-to-number str)))

(my-string-float-p "x")
nil

(my-string-float-p "0")
nil

(my-string-float-p "0.0")
t
```

Comment: `my-string-float-p` gives `t` for `(my-string-float-p "0.1Hello")`. Is that intended behavior?

Comment: Right, `(string-to-number "0.1Hello")` returns `0.1`.  It's documented (trailing chars are ignored), so it's "intended" in that respect.  Whether it's *useful* behaviour rather depends on your use-case. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: for my use case its ok

Answer (score 3):

Since one can edit program texts in many programming languages with emacs it is important to note that the floating point syntax can vary with the programming language. For an instance [`1.2d3` is a floating point number in Fortran](http://tpcg.io/g22h2J) but not in Elisp.

In the following I present a function `my-string-float-p` that returns `t` if the whole string is read as a floating point number by the Elisp reader.

One can interpret the first object in the string as lisp by `read` and
test this object with `floatp`.

If `read` has gobbled all characters from the string that is the only
thing represented by the string.

```el
(defun my-string-float-p (str)
  "Non-nil if string STR represents a floating point number."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert str)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (condition-case nil
        (and (floatp (read (current-buffer)))
             (eobp))
        (error nil))))
```

Test suite:

```el
(my-string-float-p "x")
nil
(my-string-float-p "0")
nil
(my-string-float-p "0.0")
t
(my-string-float-p "8.3")
t
(my-string-float-p "0.1Hello")
nil
(my-string-float-p "0.1 Hello")
nil
(my-string-float-p "(")
nil
(my-string-float-p ")")
nil
```

Comment: `(defun f (s) (floatp (read s)))` does the same thing for a string arg, no? At least for your test suite it seems to.

Comment: @Drew I added a test case `(my-string-float-p "0.1 Hello")` which does not return the expected `nil` with `(f "0.1 Hello")` and your `(defun f (s) (floatp (read s)))`.

Answer (score 1):

```el
(defun string-float-p (str)
  "Non-nil if string STR represents a floating point number."
  (let ((rd  (read-from-string str)))
    (and (floatp (car rd))  (eq (cdr rd) (length str)))))
```

Comment: Protection against reading strings with erroneous lisp is also necessary `(condition-case nil ... (error nil))`.

Comment: A similar effect would be possible with `(let ((rd (read (concat "(" str ")")))) (and (floatp (car rd)) (null (cdr rd))))`. That version would ignore spaces at front and tail of `str`.